# C# и SMTP соединение

Tags: c#, smtp

Как на C# установить соединение с SMTP, узнать успешно ли оно установилось, и НЕ отправлять сообщение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Могу ошибаться, но возможно только ручками... подключиться к smtp порту и посылать команды вручную, сначала EHLO xxx потом AUTH LOGIN и далее кодированные в BASE64 логин и пароль, ну  и после каждой команды ждать правильного ответа. Последним ответом должно быть что-то типа 235 Authentication succeeded, по идее это значит что соединение успешное пароль/логи правильный, и соответственно если Вам не нужно тестить авторизацию достаточно EHLO.

Comment: Спасибо, так, думаю, даже лучше будет, чем классы юзать

Answer (score 2):

Тоже столкнулся с необходимостью проверки соединения с smtp сервером + с проверкой имени пользователя и пароля без отправки письма.
Доработал ответ на вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372742/can-i-test-smtpclient-before-calling-client-send/372794#answer-2860887

Мои наработки ([на github](https://github.com/B2BFamily/SmtpValidator))

```
public static bool ValidateCredentials(string login, string password, string server, int port, bool enableSsl) {
        SmtpConnectorBase connector;
        if (enableSsl) {
            connector = new SmtpConnectorWithSsl(server, port);
        } else {
            connector = new SmtpConnectorWithoutSsl(server, port);
        }

        if (!connector.CheckResponse(220)) {
            return false;
        }

        connector.SendData($"HELO {Dns.GetHostName()}{SmtpConnectorBase.EOF}");
        if (!connector.CheckResponse(250)) {
            return false;
        }

        connector.SendData($"AUTH LOGIN{SmtpConnectorBase.EOF}");
        if (!connector.CheckResponse(334)) {
            return false;
        }

        connector.SendData(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{login}")) + SmtpConnectorBase.EOF);
        if (!connector.CheckResponse(334)) {
            return false;
        }

        connector.SendData(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{password}")) + SmtpConnectorBase.EOF);
        if (!connector.CheckResponse(235)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

SmtpConnectorBase:

```
internal abstract class SmtpConnectorBase {
    protected string SmtpServerAddress { get; set; }
    protected int Port { get; set; }
    public const string EOF = "\r\n";

    protected SmtpConnectorBase(string smtpServerAddress, int port) {
        SmtpServerAddress = smtpServerAddress;
        Port = port;
    }

    public abstract bool CheckResponse(int expectedCode);
    public abstract void SendData(string data);
}
```

SmtpConnectorWithoutSsl:

```
internal class SmtpConnectorWithoutSsl : SmtpConnectorBase {
    private Socket _socket = null;

    public SmtpConnectorWithoutSsl(string smtpServerAddress, int port) : base(smtpServerAddress, port) {
        IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(smtpServerAddress);
        IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(hostEntry.AddressList[0], port);
        _socket = new Socket(endPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        //try to connect and test the rsponse for code 220 = success
        _socket.Connect(endPoint);

    }

    ~SmtpConnectorWithoutSsl() {
        try {
            if (_socket != null) {
                _socket.Close();
                _socket.Dispose();
                _socket = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception) {
            ;
        }

    }

    public override bool CheckResponse(int expectedCode) {
        while (_socket.Available == 0) {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        byte[] responseArray = new byte[1024];
        _socket.Receive(responseArray, 0, _socket.Available, SocketFlags.None);
        string responseData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseArray);
        int responseCode = Convert.ToInt32(responseData.Substring(0, 3));
        if (responseCode == expectedCode) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override void SendData(string data) {
        byte[] dataArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        _socket.Send(dataArray, 0, dataArray.Length, SocketFlags.None);
    }
}
```

SmtpConnectorWithSsl:

```
internal class SmtpConnectorWithSsl : SmtpConnectorBase {
    private SslStream _sslStream = null;
    private TcpClient _client = null;

    public SmtpConnectorWithSsl(string smtpServerAddress, int port) : base(smtpServerAddress, port) {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(smtpServerAddress, port);

        _sslStream = new SslStream(
            client.GetStream(),
            false,
            new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
            null
            );
        // The server name must match the name on the server certificate.
        try {
            _sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(smtpServerAddress);
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            _sslStream = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
            if (e.InnerException != null) {
                Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
            client.Close();
        }
    }

    ~SmtpConnectorWithSsl() {
        try {
            if (_sslStream != null) {
                _sslStream.Close();
                _sslStream.Dispose();
                _sslStream = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception) {
            ;
        }

        try {
            if (_client != null) {
                _client.Close();
                _client = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception) {
            ;
        }
    }

    // The following method is invoked by the RemoteCertificateValidationDelegate.
    private static bool ValidateServerCertificate(
          object sender,
          X509Certificate certificate,
          X509Chain chain,
          SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) {
        if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
            return true;

        Console.WriteLine("Certificate error: {0}", sslPolicyErrors);

        // Do not allow this client to communicate with unauthenticated servers.
        return false;
    }

    public override bool CheckResponse(int expectedCode) {
        if (_sslStream == null) {
            return false;
        }
        var message = ReadMessageFromStream(_sslStream);
        int responseCode = Convert.ToInt32(message.Substring(0, 3));
        if (responseCode == expectedCode) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override void SendData(string data) {
        byte[] messsage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        // Send hello message to the server. 
        _sslStream.Write(messsage);
        _sslStream.Flush();
    }

    private string ReadMessageFromStream(SslStream stream) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        StringBuilder messageData = new StringBuilder();
        int bytes = -1;
        do {
            bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            // Use Decoder class to convert from bytes to UTF8
            // in case a character spans two buffers.
            Decoder decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
            char[] chars = new char[decoder.GetCharCount(buffer, 0, bytes)];
            decoder.GetChars(buffer, 0, bytes, chars, 0);
            messageData.Append(chars);
            // Check for EOF.
            if (messageData.ToString().IndexOf(EOF) != -1) {
                break;
            }
        } while (bytes != 0);

        return messageData.ToString();
    }
}
```